# Using custom image resizing script in a page

Tags: customization, images, post-thumbnails

I am using the [aqua-resizer](https://github.com/syamilmj/Aqua-Resizer) to create custom image sizes and cropping. However, I am also using a theme with a built-in page editor and module-based layout.

I am able to get the aqua-resizer script to work fine outside of the page builder, such as in a custom.php file elsewhere on the site, by using it in a loop.

What I'd also like to do is use the aqua-resizer on modules in the page builder, by modifying some of the theme's existing code.

I've tried removing this line from the intended module:

```
<?php echo $this->get_image('td_180x135');?>
```

and replacing with:

```
<?php $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full'); $image = aq_resize( $img_url, 240, 120, true ); ?><img src="<?php echo $image ?>" />
```

but it doesn't load the images with the aqua-resizer script.

Is it possible that the aqua-resizer script needs to be contained within a custom function to make this work outside of standalone php files?